What does a locale’s codeset get used for?
According to glibc’s manual:

Most locale names follow XPG syntax and consist of up to four parts:
language[_territory[.codeset]][@modifier]


For example, you could have a locale named zh_CN.GB18030 which would use the GB 18030 character encoding, or you could have a locale named zh_CN.UTF-8 which would use the UTF-8 character encoding.
Here’s where I’m confused: let’s say that I switch from a zh_CN.UTF-8 locale to a zh_CN.GB18030 locale. In that situation, some things that used to be encoded in UTF-8 are now going to be encoded in GB 18030. Which things will now be encoded in GB 18030? Will stdin, stdout and stderr use GB 18030? What about argv? What about filesystem paths?
Technically, a program can do whatever it wants and ignore the locale completely, but let’s assume that programs are doing the correct thing here. What is supposed to be encoded in GB 18030 if I use a zh_CN.GB18030 locale?
